# WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount Sql Collation Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-webpages, simplemembership

If Sql Server database collation is **Turkish_CI_AS**, I get that error at below cause UPPER function in SELECT Query in "GetUserId" method of **SimpleMembershipProvider.cs** class.

SQL UPPER('info') is not equal to "info".ToUpperInvariant() in Turkish_CI_AS

Sql Server Database Collation : Turkish_CI_AS

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("info", "123456");
```

> **Exception Details: System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException: The Provider
>   encountered an unknown error.**

Answer (score 1):

You should change the collation of UserProfile.UserName column in DB from Turkish_CI_AS to Latin1_General_CI_AS or any other at the moment. So, this must be bug.